# How to change analyzer of an existing Neo4j index using Cypher

Tags: indexing, neo4j, analyzer

What is the best Cypher command to change the analyzer of an existing index in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the documentation:

> The `db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex` and
>   `db.index.fulltext.createRelationshipIndex` takes an optional fourth
>   argument, called `config`. The `config` parameter is a map from string to
>   string, and can be used to set index-specific configuration settings.
>   The `analyzer` setting can be used to configure an index-specific
>   analyzer. The possible values for the `analyzer` setting can be listed
>   with the `db.index.fulltext.listAvailableAnalyzers` procedure.

However, if you are running the Enterprise Edition of neo4j in a clustered environment, there is currently a warning:

> Using index-specific settings via the `config` parameter is
>   experimental, because these settings currently do not get replicated
>   in a clustered environment. See the [Fulltext Schema Indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/performance/index-configuration/fulltext/) section of
>   the Operations Manual, for how to configure the default fulltext index
>   configurations in [neo4j.conf](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/configuration/file-locations/).

Here is an example of how to create a fulltext index that uses the "lithuanian" analyzer:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex(
  "titlesAndDescriptions",
  ["Movie", "Book"],
  ["title", "description"],
  {analyzer: "lithuanian"}
)
```

But there does not seem to be a way, using Cypher, to *change* the analyzer of an existing fulltext index. In fact, even if that were possible, it may not be a good idea. Since the contents of an existing index would have been created using the previous analyzer and any new additions to the index would be made with the new analyzer, index lookups could lead to very strange or error-prone results. It would be better to create an new fulltext index instead.